# Manage localization with Baml

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, baml, locbaml

I'm developping a little application in WPF and I want to localize my resources. 
I've always used resources files (.resx), but I heard about BAML that was suppose to change the way of manage localization in a WPF application.

I made my research and I found a way to translate my application using those files.

I wrote a blog post to show how I did it over [here](http://www.nmediasolutions.com/blog/post/2009/11/03/Experimentation-BAML.aspx) (french only, sorry). You can see references at the end of the post for english links.

The fact is, I really dislike this way of managing resources. I think it's way more complicated and I don't see the pros of using this method.

Am I wrong or did I misunderstand something about BAML ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got a fairly good grasp on the concept, and yes, it is too complicated.

BAML is just compiled XAML. You're using an external tool to extract the resource, make changes, and embed your resources back. It's definately not streamlined, and hopefully this process is made easier in the future.

Even on the [documentation of the process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx), you'll notice at the bottom someone has recommended using .resx instead of this process. If this is already a method you're using for localization, you probably won't find much advantage in taking the LocBaml route.